# plesk install on docker

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, plesk

when i want to download and run plesk in my docker container i get this error message

> Warning: Cannot exists mariadb on this system: no executable /bin/systemctl
> Warning: restart service mariadb failed
> Warning: Cannot exists mariadb on this system: no executable /bin/systemctl
> ERROR while trying to stop
> MySQL
> server
> STOP Bootstrapper 18.0.40 prep-install for BASE AT Sun Jan  9 16:08:57 UTC 2022

and then my download will not finish
how can i fix this

Comment: It's hard to answer this without seeing your Dockerfile or any of your other source code.  I can say, in general, that commands like `systemctl` or `service` just don't work in Docker, and perhaps suggest maybe you want to split your setup into multiple containers, but that's just speculation from the error message.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have created the [docker-systemctl-replacement](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement) script to help packaging software that is not ready to be containerized.

Specifically I can run a full LAMP stack in a single container which may cover your use case altogether. Have a look at the examples in [docker-systemctl-images](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-images)